# SQL server grouping on NULLABLE column

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a situation in SQL Server (with a legacy DB) that i can't understand why?

I have a table A (about 2 million rows) that have column CODE that allow null. The number rows that have CODE = NULL is just several (< 10 rows). When i run the query:

```
select code, sum(C1)
from A
-- where code is not null
group by code;
```

It runs forever. But when i un-comment the where clause, it took around 1.5s (still too slow, right?)

Could anyone here help me pointing out what are the possible causes for such situation?

Execution plan add:
[image]

Comment: Please provide your execution plan with `WHERE` and without...

Comment: probably you would need to create an index on code column

Comment: Indices are the first thing i think of so indices for code and C1 have been created. But when I run the query with the execution plan, it complained missing index and created a "Nonclustered index" on A(code) include C1 for me. After that, all queries were very fast again.... Any resource for this specific case? :-)

Comment: Hi @TrầnĐườngTú have you done some testing with an index and see how it goes?

Comment: @Trần Đường Tú please provide execution plan. We don't have any crystal ball to answer on your question :(

Comment: "and without..." thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, NULL values cannot be stored by a conventional index. So even if you have an index on *code*, your WHERE condition cannot benefit from that index.

If C1 is included in the index (which I assume is NOT NULL), things are different, because all the tuples (code=NULL, C1=(*some value*)) can and will be indexed. These are few, according to your question; so SQL Server can get a considerable speedup by just returning the rows for all these tuples.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a few words about performance. We have a several variants in your case.

Indexes View -

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.t', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.t
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.t (
    ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    Code VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    [Status] INT NULL
)
GO

ALTER VIEW dbo.v
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT Code, [Status] = SUM(ISNULL([Status], 0)), Cnt = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.t
    WHERE Code IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Code
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.v (Code)

SELECT Code, [Status]
FROM dbo.v
```

Filtered Index -

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.t (Code)
    INCLUDE ([Status])
    WHERE Code IS NOT NULL
```

Will wait your second execution plan.

Comment: Sorry but i can't wait for the "without" to be finished :-)... so, no execution plan then

Comment: @Trần Đường Tú please check about `estimated execution plan` ;) and how to save plan as `*.sqlplan`